# Is there a way to hide a Steam game from your recently played list?

Tags: steam

A friend of mine said he's seen me playing a game (Batman: Arkham Origins) on Steam while I was at work. Since he only has two friends in his list I tend to believe him (ruling out a mix-up)

But the game does not show up on my recently played list. **Is there a way to play a game without appearing in that list or to delete an entry?**

Just to be sure, I changed my Steam password.

Comment: Games that are not steam game will show you playing even if you are just updating (a friend is showing playing Planetside 2 but I know he's updating it). There might be some steam games that do the same.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau if your start Planetside 2 in Steam, will it just start another launcher of planetside then?

Comment: @Nitro.de Yes. Same goes with Ubisoft games that requires UPlay. I haven't noted if I started a UPlay game with Steam if having just the Uplay launcher made me "playing xxx game" in Steam.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau as i know those launchers will count as "in game XYZ" that explains why you see your friend playing while he's just updating

Comment: It was Batman: Arkham Origins (steam version)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No its not possible to delete or remove those entrys since they are all stored server side i assume. If you search you find people on reddit having similar issues, which can be traced back to a buggy steam beta version and free weekends showing wrong information on the beta client.

http://www.reddit.com/r/Steam/comments/2uwnwn/

Maybe those bugs and your friend seeing you in a game you didnt even play at the time are related

Comment: good reddit link, didn't noticed that for now

Comment: Ugh, apparently this problem hasn't been fixed yet.  The damn client _always_ adds the same 5 random games to the top of the list every time steam is restarted.  I can't even use the recent list even if I wanted to.  Manually removing each one individually is moot, it will be added back by steam the next time I start...

Answer (score 2):

If you disconnect from the internet while playing the game, it won't count towards your hours played.

If you think someone else might have been on your account, Steam logs where people access your account from via IP address. So if you log into your account from a new computer, it will require email verification before you can login.

Answer (score 0):

On December 20<sup>th</sup> 2023, the [Steam Beta Client added an ability](https://store.steampowered.com/news/app/593110/view/3901870709962551195) to mark a game as private, which should resolve achieve what you are looking for:

> Starting today you’ll be able to mark specific games as private and they’ll disappear from anywhere they’d be viewed by someone other than you. That includes: your ownership, in-game status, playtime, and activity in that game. This additional control allows you to keep most of your Steam Library visible to your friends, so they can see what you are playing and join in, yet also keep a few of those games just to yourself.

There is also this [FAQ](https://help.steampowered.com/en/faqs/view/1150-C06F-4D62-4966) about this feature, which includes how to set a game as private:

> There are three places where a game can be marked as private:
>
> - From the Steam Client - You can mark a game as private from the "Manage" submenu on the game itself.  This menu is available from
>   right-clicking on a game or clicking the gear icon on the game details
>   page.  Additionally, it can be found under the "Privacy" settings in
>   the game properties dialog.  This option is only available when the
>   Steam Client is online and connected to Steam.
> - From your web browser - You can mark a game as private on your Steam Community Profile games list.
> - From your shopping cart - Before you complete the purchase of a game, you can mark it private on the cart page.

You can opt into the beta via the Steam application by going to Steam → Settings → Interface → Client Beta Participation and change the drop down to "Steam Beta Update".  You can also follow [this guide](https://help.steampowered.com/en/faqs/view/276C-85A0-C531-AFA3).